# Built my docker image with docker id in tag but the image is not showing up in local repo

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm using MacOS, installed Docker Desktop. I have a private registry in Docker Hub, my docker id `myusername`.

On my terminal, I built my image successful:

```
$ docker build -t myusername/my-app:1.0.3 -f Dockerfile .
[+] Building 2.9s (8/8) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 103B                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:12                                                            2.7s
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 776B                                                                                     0.0s
 => [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/node:12@sha256:8b4c721e513da8cfeda2f481668648ad9a4ec582faff9f43f1cf1c133dd3cba8      0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/node:12@sha256:8b4c724e613da8cfeda2f481668648ad9a4ec582faff9f42f1dfcc133dd3cba8      0.0s
 => CACHED [2/2] COPY app.js /app.js                                                                                  0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                               0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:129289afecab3027a14786500a8ab943256385d618b761ad1843a1af5f214300                          0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/myusername/my-app:1.0.3
```

Then, I run `docker images`:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                      TAG                   IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
<none>                                          <none>                1702444e49d3   3 months ago    58MB
rabbitmq                                        latest                6bfb45074bc0   3 months ago    220MB
```

The result shows me all other images I had built but there is no image named `myusername/my-app:1.0.3` showing.  Why is that?

Comment: It might show `myusername/my-app` as image name `1.0.3` is your tag (version)

Comment: Are those both in the same terminal window?  Are you using some other container environment like Minikube at the same time?  What does `echo $DOCKER_HOST` say?

Comment: Yes, same terminal window.  I am not using other container environment, but I have `kubectl` for deploying the container to a remote k8s cluster.  The `echo $DOCKER_HOST` says empty on my machine. I don't have the env variable name.